# React native - eslintrc - prettierrc: how to prevent removing of parentheses around one element in JSX

Tags: react-native, jsx, prettier, eslintrc

I just created new react-native app and the eslint change this:

```
return (
    <Component />
);
```

to

```
return <Component />;
```

I tried to change the .eslintrc and .prettierrc files and nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

first, create a file call it `.prettierrc.js` in your project main folder and then write these commends

```
module.exports = {
arrowParens: false,
};
```

or

```
module.exports = {
  arrowParens: "avoid",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In this response, I took as a statement that you were using eslint along with prettier, with the `prettier` extension  and the `prettier` plugin within your .eslintrc, as well as the existence of rule `"prettier/prettier": "error"`.

The error brought here comes from prettier, since the error is found like this:

```
Replace `(⏎······<Component·/>⏎····)` with `<Component·/>
```

However, there is no option in prettier to configure the behaviour on the changes you mentioned. Nonetheless, there exist some workarounds:

**1)** Disable the line causing the changes:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
return (
  <Component />
);
```

**2)** Use the option `requirePragma`, where you need to insert on top of every file you want prettier to watch the comment `/**@format */`. However this technique requires changes all over your files. Maybe not the best solution.

**3)** Use only eslint, since eslint doesn't consider this writing as an error by default. (or does not treat this case at all).

A question to ask; why want to keep the format with the parentheses? The changes take fewer lines, and the code remains readable.

Hope that it helped you in a way.