# How to disable VS Code prettier from deleting extra parenthesis

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using prettier in VS Code for typescript. It always remove extra parenthesis, for example

```
(new Controller()).setData(data).run();
```

will always be format into

```
new Controller().setData(data).run();
```

Which rules handle this deletion? I did see a similar rule in eslint: no-extra-parens. However, I am not using this rule in my eslint file.

Comment: FWIW, parentheses are useless in this code, `new Ctor().method()` is the way it's commonly written in JS, this is the problem that Prettier addresses.

Comment: @EstusFlask the fact it still works is certainly not the point of this Q ;-)

Comment: I have the same issue with math expressions `y + (height / 2)` will be formatted into `y + height / 2` which is different result

Answer (score 0):

Add a file `.prettierrc` in the project's root folder with the following contents.

```
module.exports = {
  arrowParens: "avoid"
};
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322297/13099086) answer.